# Vim 9.0.1420 update: opening the same file twice without warning message is unfortunately now possible?

Tags: swap-file, vim9

I observed that in the recent update for Vim, specifically `vim 9.0.1420`, it is now possible to create a text file, open it, and then open the same file through another terminal window without encountering the familiar warning message related to `.swp` files. This message was previously displayed before the update and helped prevent editing an already opened file.
Would anybody help me (scritpnames test, etc) to narrow down the cause of this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: I can't repro on 9.0.1450.

Comment: "Would anybody help me (scritpnames test, etc) to narrow down the cause of this problem?" Well, why don't you get ahead and do all that right from the bat?

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Can you reproduce the problem when you start Vim with `vim -u NONE -i NONE`? Can you reproduce the problem with `vim --clean`?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Thanks. If on one terminal I open `vim -u NONE test.txt` and through another terminal window `vim -u NONE test.txt` , I can see the `.swp` warning. Same with `vim --clean test.txt`. Could you help me to narrow down where the problem is? Super, many thanks

Comment: `vim --clean` starts Vim without plugins. The "problem" is probably with one of your plugin. My advice would be to do some kind of binary search (disable half of them, disable the other half, ...) to find the culprit.

Comment: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)